# How to compute 90-th percentile of data with Inf values?

Tags: r, quantiles, discrete-data

I need to compute an effective diameter is 90-th percentile of the distribution of shortest path lengths of a graph.

My attempt is:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(4)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(n=50, p.or.m=100, type="gnm", directed=TRUE, loops=FALSE)
sp <- as.vector(shortest.paths(g, algorithm = "dijkstra", mode="out"))
sp <- sp[!is.na(sp) & !is.infinite(sp)] # delete NaN and Inf
quantile(sp, 0.9)
# 7
```

In the sapmle data the Inf values were deleted.

**Question.** Is it suitable to delete Inf value for the q-th percentile calculation?

Comment: The algorithm might not work if there are inf's in the array, however if inf is a possible outcome (and not a placeholder) you should consider it.

Comment: An `Inf` in your shortest distances presumably means that some nodes are not reachable from others. An undirected graph would be disconnected. It probably makes more sense to think about what you plan on doing with your 90th percentile and think about whether calculating this quantile for disconnected graphs makes sense, or whether you should treat connected components separately or something like that.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/d5200c4730738bad064321420bebb8f2) is a Python gist covering the `network` equivalent, although `networkx.all_pairs_shortest_path_length` doesn't yield infinite path lengths normally. Not sure what would happen if you gave it infinite weights in the original graph though.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete these values when looking at the quantiles then you are implicitly making an inference about the quantiles *of the conditional distribution when the outcome is not infinity*, instead of the marginal distribution of your data.  For this type of problem, you should consider what the `Inf` outcome means in your data and decide if you want to make an inference that is conditional on this outcome not occurring (using the conditional distribution), or an inference that allows for this outcome (using the marginal distribution).  That decision will require contextual judgment based on the meaning of the `Inf` outcome and the goal of your analysis.